# Playing youtube videos in a custom player using AVFoundation

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube-api, avfoundation, mpmovieplayer

AVFoundation allows a developer to create a custom Video Player instead of using Apple's own fullscreen MPMoviePlayer.

In my project, I'm using this approach to achieve something close to what the YouTube iOS app does, which is to have a "canvas" view up on top where playback takes place, along with several controls and text labels at the bottom:

[image: A very skilled Jedi]

As you know, a YouTube URL "points" to HTML data, and it is meant to be used within a UIWebView. Tapping on the thumbnail inside this UIWebView brings up a fullscreen Player, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

I would like to know if the YouTube API provides a URL pointing to the actual video (mp4 file), so that I may use it along AVFoundation.

I want to find a legal way to do this, so it should definetely comply to both Apple's and Google's terms of service.

Thanks,

Comment: You should check out https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser and see what they're doing, although I'm not sure it falls in line with their terms of service

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out. I'm looking for a legal way to accomplish this, hopefully there's one.

Comment: Be sure to check it out, I've only heard that about the TOS -- never researched it myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is by adding an overlay UIView, which you can place over any part of the screen. And putting it on top of the UIWebView, and set it to not respond to user interactions. As you can change size and placement and making it transparent, you can effectively choose which user interactions you want and which you don't want. And you will not mess around with youTube ToS in any way.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think that playing that video will always result in the app triggering a full-screen modal player, right?

Comment: Looking at the UIWebView reference I found this property:

    @property (nonatommic) allowsInlineMediaPlayback

This might do the trick.

Comment: It seems that to get it to work that way you need to make a native HTML5 page and display that in the UIWebView. Probably why this feature is disabled in iPhone and not iPad is the small screen.
On iPad allowsInlineMediaPlayback is set to YES and on iPod/iPhone no.

Comment: I kind of solved this problem, by not resorting to AVFoundation at all.Instead, I ended up embedding YouTube's HTML5 player into a UIWebView. You can customize this player by some degree by including parameters in YouYube's URL and then you can use javascript to interact with the player, using your own UIKit views.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id= with the video id appended contains the mp4 url, may require some regex work (found here: https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser/blob/master/YoutubeParser/Classes/HCYoutubeParser.m)

Comment: Do you know if this violates Youtube's ToS?

Comment: haven't researched, not sure